# when i run my program and click button_1 error #1009 showed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

```
function f2l_ClickToGoToScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(5, "Scene2");
}



button_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f2l_ClickToGoToScene_2);

function f2l_ClickToGoToScene_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(10, "Scene3");
}



button_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f2l_ClickToGoToScene_3);

function f2l_ClickToGoToScene_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(15, "Scene4");
}



 button_4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f2l_ClickToGoToScene_4);

 function f2l_ClickToGoToScene_4(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(20, "Scene5");
 }



button_5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f2l_ClickToGoToScene_5);

function f2l_ClickToGoToScene_5(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(25, "Scene6");
}



button_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f2l_ClickToGoToScene_6);

function f2l_ClickToGoToScene_6(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(30, "Scene7");
}



button_7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f2l_ClickToGoToScene_7);

function f2l_ClickToGoToScene_7(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(35, "Scene8");
}



button_8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f2l_ClickToGoToScene_8);

function f2l_ClickToGoToScene_8(event:MouseEvent):void
{
MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(40, "Scene9");
}
```

> TypeError: Error #1009 cannot acces a property or method of a null
>   object refrence.    at
>   Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame182()[untitled_fla.MainTimeline::frame182:1]
>   at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndplay()    at
>   Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/f1_ClickToGoToScene()[Untitled_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:7]

Comment: Please add some explanation in your question. Which function is called when you clicks button_1.

Comment: Show `f1_ClickToGoToScene()` function.

Answer (score 0):

'Null object reference' indicates that the object referenced that threw the error wasn't instantiated. In Flash Pro, normally this is caused by not labeling your instance properly on the stage. Without more information or seeing your .fla, I would guess that your "Scene2" instance never got labeled as such.

Click the object on the stage, go to properties, and type in the instance name. I believe if your navigating different scenes, you still need to label each scene instance.

Tim